# problem with understanding the python list

Tags: python-3.x

```
eg.a

x = 10
y = x
x = 10 + 2
a = x

print(x)
print(y)
print(a)
```

this gives output:
12 , 10 , 12
and i understand it.

but

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x = a
a.insert(1, 'x')
print(x)
```

gives ['a', 'x', 'b', 'c', 'd']

what i don't understand is this should give ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as i printed the value of x=a before i inserted the char x to the first index of list  a . like in eg.a list does not follow the steps. why?

Comment: Do you know that by doing `x = a` you're not cloning the list.  `x` just refers to the `a` object memory address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better answer somewhere but here goes.

Python `list`s are mutable. A python `int` is not.
But what does that mean?

Well being mutable really just comes down to being able to change the values of an object.
With an `int` this is not possible.

Lets review your example.

```
x = 10
```

Here you assign an `10` to the variable `x`. This creates an integer object who's value cannot be changed.
To view the `id` of this object we can `print(id(x))`.

On your next line you assign this object to `y`.

```
y = x
```

We can see they both refer to the same object with `print(id(x) == id(y))`.

So here you may think you are assigning a new value to the same object, however what is really happening is python is creating an entirely new object for you.

```
x = 10 + 2
```

The same thing would in fact happen with `x += 2` even though that may not be obvious.
You can check this again with `print(id(x) == id(y))` or `print(x is y)`.

As you may have guessed, `list`s have methods that do in fact change the `list` in place.
When you used

```
a.insert(1, 'x')
```

you did not reassign a new `list` to `a` so in essence, `x` will reflect your change there as well.

Ned Batchelder gave an excellent [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) at pycon a few years ago that really clears up a lot of the confusion. If you have some spare time I would definitely give it a watch.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are assigning x=a. Here, x refers to data location address of a, not copying data. So, when a change, then it is updated. As well as x is referring to the same location. So, you getting this result.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a string(character to be precise) with 'x'. If you want to add x remove the '  ' marks and just write

```
a.insert(1, x)
```

Comment: thats not my problem. my problem is that i set x = a before inserting char 'x' to a so when i print (x) why do i get the list that contains the char 'x'?

Comment: Its because no new variable(object) is created, x just refers to a. You can say like its just another way of referring to a.